# Jumping to previous prompt in terminal

Tags: linux, terminal, tmux, iterm, terminal-emulator

In a terminal, are there any shortcuts to jump to a previous/next prompt? Scrolling up and trying to find the start of a log slows down my workflow.

I'm using iTerm on OSX, but this should be applicable to any Unix terminals. A solution in Tmux would help as well.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Newest iTerm2 beta has a "shell integration" feature which offers such shortcut keys.

If you've installed it successfully, you see a small arrow in front of the prompts. Press `Cmd + Shift + Up/Down` to jump to the previous/next one. [See the documentation](https://iterm2.com/shell_integration.html) for more cool stuff.

Comment: Any idea how to set it up with this feature? I've installed shell integration, but not sure what to do after that.

Comment: If you've install it successfully, you see a small arrow in front of the prompts. Press Cmd+Shift+Up/Down to jump to the prev/next one. See https://iterm2.com/shell_integration.html for further cool stuff.

Answer (score 0):

"history" piped to "grep" gives you past inputs without the output. But you then have to copy and paste to use it. Once you've reused something this way, up-arrow for previous, works.

Answer (score 0):

In tmux, you can enter copy-mode (bound to `[` by default). From there you can do a reverse search with `Ctrl-r` in emacs-mode or `?` in vi-mode. Tmux will ask you for a search term. If your prompt has a unique string to search for, it should be pretty easy to find. While still in copy-mode, you can use `n` to repeat the search.